# how to optimize my mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: vehicle_c2c_car_source and vehicle_c2c_appoint_task.
The structure of vehicle_c2c_car_source:

/********************************/

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT
```

/******************************/

vehicle_c2c_appoint_task

/******************************/

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`car_source_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
`status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

The value of status can be 0,1,2. one car_source_id can have many status.

The first goal is to get all the car_source that the amount of status records is less than 3.

The second goal is to get the amount of the status records when status is equal to 1.

The output should something like that:

22222(id of status records)   1111(car_source_id)  title(title) 4(amount of the status records when status = 1)

My current solution is first to get all the car_source that meet the first goal and then query vehicle_c2c_appoint_task table in a loop to accomplish the second goal.

```
SELECT cs.id, pt.car_source_id, cs.title, 
FROM vehicle_c2c_car_source AS cs
JOIN vehicle_c2c_appoint_task AS pt ON cs.id = pt.car_source_id
WHERE 1
AND pt.appoint_status NOT IN (2,6)
GROUP BY pt.car_source_id HAVING count(pt.car_source_id) < 3
```

In the loop:

```
SELECT count(*) as count 
FROM vehicle_c2c_appoint_task 
WHERE status = 1
group by car_source_id
```

I think it is not a good idea to put the query in a loop. How can i get all the value in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is hard to follow.  But you can combine the two queries by using conditional aggregation, both in the `SELECT` and the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT cs.id, pt.car_source_id, cs.title, SUM(status = 1) as cnt
FROM vehicle_c2c_car_source cs JOIN
      vehicle_c2c_appoint_task pt
      ON cs.id = pt.car_source_id
GROUP BY pt.car_source_id
HAVING SUM(pt.appoint_status NOT IN (2, 6)) < 3;
```